# Allow to choose directory using Angular FileSaver.js

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I am using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to save files from Angular.

However, I would like to allow the user to choose the directory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. It is the browser's choice whether to present the user with a "Save As.." dialog box, or whether to just automatically download to the "Downloads" folder.

For example, here is the [setting for Chrome that controls this behaviour](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759#comp_change_default):

[image: Google Chrome setting controlling file download location]

Comment: You gave me the answer that I needed. Thank you a lot

Comment: @JohnWillmerCubillosVega-C No problem! If this answered your question, don't forget to [upvote & mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)